# Why won't google maps show on my website, I have been using the developers website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```js
/* This is the javascript function that makes the map load */
  function initMap() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: {
        lat: 44.540,
        lng: -78.546
      },
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
```

```css
/* This is the basic css */

#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Javascript called into the html page -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where the callback is defined when embedding the Google maps library? It seems that `&callback=initMap` is missing from the querystring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function is not calling use $(document).ready(function()()) for call your function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
     <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: {lat: 44.540, lng: -78.546},
      zoom: 8
    });
   
});
     </script>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to register an application and get an API key when including the javascript library from Google

Comment: Thanks guys I got it to work and I really appreciate all your help

Comment: I am trying to use the api key but wont work with it but It will work code.rider snippet

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a DOM listener that will execute the `initMap()` function on window load.

try this

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.540, -78.546),
    zoom: 8
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" ></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```